# Or condition in PHP with str_replace

Tags: php

I have been looking to use or condition in PHP in str_replace when array is used.
Ex:Currently below is the some code str_replace line in one of my code snippet.

```
$header['model'] = str_replace(array('myexample', 'i'), '', $header['model']);
```

Can I use or condition as below

```
$header['model'] = str_replace(array('myexample', 'i') || array('myexample1', 'i'), '', $header['model']);
```

Any help/suggestions, please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$header['model'] = str_replace(array('myexample', 'i') || array('myexample1', 'i'), '', $header['model']);
```

This **OR** condition will not work and **str_replace** only replace 1 array values.

You can merge your array and then can use str_replace for both.

**Try this-**

```
$a1 = array('myexample', 'i');
$a2 = array('myexample1', 'i');
$a3 = array_merge($a1,$a2);
echo str_replace( $a3 , '', $header['model']);
```